# How to add value into shiny htmlTemplate without line breaks

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to add script that as string from template:

```
  htmlTemplate(
    filename = "foo.RHtml",
    greetings = "hello World"
  )
```

**foo.RHtml**

```
<script>
var x = '{{greetings}}';
</script>
```

but shiny is adding line breaks before {{ and after }} so my code is not valid JavaScript. I could use backticks but it will fail when using shiny test that use PhantomJS that don't allow to use ES6.

I can add quotes into the string in R, but I want to know, if there is a way to make it not insert those line breaks.

Comment: its an open issue, see here: https://github.com/rstudio/htmltools/issues/19#issuecomment-446230008.